# How to create new window through window menu in Tauri?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, tauri

I've tried to create new app window through window menu. But there i faced with issue that method

> create_window

is not available

How can i do that?

```
 #![cfg_attr(
all(not(debug_assertions), target_os = "windows"),
windows_subsystem = "windows"
)]

use tauri::{Menu, WindowMenuEvent, Wry, Submenu, CustomMenuItem, WindowUrl, WindowBuilder};


pub fn create() -> Menu {
    let test_menu = Menu::new()
        .add_item(CustomMenuItem::new("new_window", "Create new window"));

    Menu::new()
        .add_submenu(Submenu::new("Test", test_menu))

}


pub fn handler(event: WindowMenuEvent<Wry>) {
    match event.menu_item_id() {
        "new_window" => {
            let mut window = event.window().clone();

        }
        _ => {}
    }
}


fn main() {
    tauri::Builder::default()
        .menu(create())
        .on_menu_event(handler)
        .run(tauri::generate_context!())
        .expect("error while running tauri application");
}
```

I created menu and cloned main window(i need to create same window) in event

Comment: Seems like this function was only present before the 1.0.0 release of Tauri. You may want to use [builder](https://docs.rs/tauri/latest/tauri/window/struct.Window.html#method.builder) instead.

Answer (score 1):

There are several examples provided by Tauri's documentation:

**1. Rust**

```rust
#[tauri::command]
async fn open_docs(handle: tauri::AppHandle) {
  let docs_window = tauri::WindowBuilder::new(
    &handle,
    "external", /* the unique window label */
    tauri::WindowUrl::External("https://tauri.app/".parse().unwrap())
  ).build().unwrap();
}
```

**2. JavaScript**

```js
import { WebviewWindow } from '@tauri-apps/api/window'
const webview = new WebviewWindow('theUniqueLabel', {
  url: 'path/to/page.html',
})
// since the webview window is created asynchronously,
// Tauri emits the `tauri://created` and `tauri://error` to notify you of the creation response
webview.once('tauri://created', function () {
  // webview window successfully created
})
webview.once('tauri://error', function (e) {
  // an error occurred during webview window creation
})
```

Link to official documentation [here](https://tauri.app/v1/guides/features/multiwindow/).

Example in the repository [here](https://github.com/tauri-apps/tauri/blob/dev/examples/multiwindow/main.rs).

And as Philipp already mentioned you can get `handle` from the `event` via `let handle = event.window().app_handle();` if you want to create window as a part of your menu event handler.

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply "clone" the old window. This would go against Tauri's approach that all windows must be unique (each window has a unique id!). When you use `.clone()`, you only clone a struct which holds all relevant data for the window. However, this clone is not registered with the application in any way, therefore it wont't show up when you call `.show()` on it.

The right approach for creating a second window (with the same contents!) again would be to build one using `WindowBuilder`. You can get a clone of `AppHandle` for the `WindowBuilder`, which is used to create new windows and register them with the application. You must provide a unique id for the WindowBuilder (if you don't have to keep track of the specific window, a random number could do it. For this, use the `rand` crate).

A simple example could look like this:

```
use tauri::{Manager, WindowBuilder};

pub fn handler(event: WindowMenuEvent<Wry>) {
    match event.menu_item_id() {
        "new_window" => {
            // Get the underlying AppHandle
            let app_handle = event.window().app_handle();
            // Generate random number, then turn it into a String
            let random_number = rand::random::<i64>().to_string();
            // Build a new Window struct
            // The HTML file to use depends on which contents should be presented
            // The main window is usually "index.html"
            let window = WindowBuilder::new(&app_handle, random_number, tauri::WindowUrl::App("YOURPAGE.html".into()))

                // Any additional window configuration here

                .build()
                .expect("Failed to create window.");
            // Show the window
            window.show().expect("Failed to show window.");
        }
        _ => {}
    }
}
```

If you need to match the existing window in size, position, etc., you can retrieve the old window's config using `event.window().inner_size()`, etc.
You then need to apply these in the step where I commented `// Any additional window configuration here`.